# Deploying a ROS2 application as a standalone (self-contained) package on Windows

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

If the developer wants to send a ROS2 application to other (none technical) users, how would they go about packaging everything (dependencies, ROS2, DDS) into one standalone executable, or set of executables? They should not need to go through the ROS2 developer setup process. It should be a simple executable or an installer.

On Linux it looks like the solution is to use snaps, however this does not work on Windows. Docker for Windows is one solution, but that also involves technical expertise. I would like to send the binary (executable or installer) as a download to the user.

What are the current options to do this, and what the pros and cons of each? Would py2Exe or pyinstaller work for rclpy nodes? And is this an area that the ROS2 developers are looking into improving?

Comment: What would the application do? would it be paired with a physical robot?

Comment: Potentially. Although the robot and application would be used by a robot operator, not an engineer. Alternatively, the node could be a robot simulator, or a robot graphical user interface.

Comment: *Or other software tool

Comment: You could look at deploying it as an android app, using the android subsystem for windows like Amazon kindle does. Could also use a labview interface, web interface, or just a qt interface that doesn’t use ros but communicates with ethercat/can and a node on the robot that translates those comms to ROS. Just a few ideas

Comment: It needs to run on Windows computers I'm afraid. And the whole system needs to run on Windows computers, not just a none-ros2 GUI. I'd like to package all of the dependencies into one thing, so the end-user can simply start the application and it work, without having to install ROS2 first.
Sending Virtual Machine Images has been the best solution we have found so far, but that is very heavyweight. A piece of software should not need a whole OS virtual machine sent with it to run.

Comment: I’m missing context but why would you not be able to have non ros2 gui? ROS2 only handles communication anyway and there’s a lot of tools out there to translate between other communication protocols

Comment: The GUI has already been made and integrated with ROS2, and the user also needs to run the robot simulator nodes, the control system nodes, the utility nodes, the full stack etc. These are all ROS2 nodes, so having a non-ros2 deployment isn't an option. For context, I am looking at simplifying the deployment of ROS2 code to customers who don't have ROS2 set up on their PC. They should be able to run the nodes by simply double clicking an executable. On linux, their are "Snaps" that can help with this. Docker containers and Virtual Machines are also solutions, but I would like something lighter

Comment: Update: I seem to be getting somewhere with `pyinstaller .\src\my_pkg\my_pkg\main.py --collect-all rclpy --collect-all rosidl_parser --collect-all rcl_interfaces --collect-all builtin_interfaces --collect-all std_msgs --add-data C:\dev\ros2_humble:ros2_humble -y` . This packages ros2_humble up with the executable. However, I have RTI_CONNEXT on my development machine and for some reason the deployed version is also looking for this instead of the default.